# How to run JSHint on files with Django template markup in them?

Tags: javascript, django, jshint

I would like to run JSHint on all my Javascript source files but several of them have some embedded Django template markup. JSHint throws a ton of errors on this markup.

Is there a way to either...

1. Tell JSHint to ignore this markup
2. Run the Djnago template parser with some dummy data to generate all permutations of the rendered js file and then run JSHint on that?

I assume I could write a bunch of code to do #2 but i'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on a markup you can get away with "hiding" Django markup with JavaScript comments. We do this, for example:

```
// {% if cond %}
someJavaScriptCode();
// {% else %}
somethingElse();
// {% endif %}

// {% include "script.js" %}
```

The only thing is that you have start script.js with a blank line—otherwise `//` will eat the first legitimate line of JavaScript code you have there. I wrote a simple helper `{% includejs  %}` that does that for me automatically.

Comment: So, this gets me past 95% of my issues and is a nice simple solution but now i'm worried about errors or more appropriately missing errors because i'm testing against BOTH branches of the IF. Do you ever find that to be a problem in practice?

Comment: Yeah, I did have that problem. But ended up avoiding it because I refactored our app in a way where Django templates are used to get dynamic data only. Everything else is raw JavaScript on CDN. Not sure if it is helpful at all, sorry. :-\

Comment: How do you handle individual variable includes in this case, for example, `{{variable_name}}`?

Comment: We use Django variables only in strings. We have a more complex object (just one) that actually holds everything we need—for it we stringify and then parse it. Something like this: `var data = "{{ jsonData|parse }}";`

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a canonical way to hide Django markup (or any other content) from JSHint:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
javascript_var = {{ context_json_string_var }};
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

The same for JSLint would be:

```
/*ignore jslint start*/
javascript_var = {{ context_json_string_var }};
/*ignore jslint end*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this ugly solution. jslint thinks that "stuff =" is part of the comment.

```
var stuff;
/* {{ '*' + '/' }}
stuff = {{ variable_containing_json_object_or_list }};                      
// */
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using the --extract flag tends to work. It also gets rid of any html code you may have in the template.

```
jshint --extract=always your_template_file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I encountered 3 problems when passing django javascript templates through the jslint tool:

## Control structures

They can be easily hidden in javascript comments, just as Anton Kovalyov proposed:

```
// {{ if some_flag }}
console.log("Conditional log");
// {{ endif }}
```

## String variables

The obvious solution is to enclose django tag in double quotes. It is however worth to remember that the generated code may be invalid if the variable content isn't properly escaped:

```
var javascript_var = "{{ context_var|escapejs }}";
```

## Complex structures serialized to json

Edwin's trick works:

```
var javascript_var;
/* {{ '*' + '/' }}
javascript_var = {{ context_json_string_var }};                      
// */
```

If you include the javascript source template in the html template, you can declare a "getter" function there and access it from the javascript script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function getIt() { return {{ context_var }}; };</script>
<script type="text/javascript">{% include 'script.js' %}</script>
```

In such case the javascript source would look pretty acceptable:

```
/*global getIt*/
var haveIt = getIt();
```